# AngularJS Modular - UI-Router doesn't work

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to move my old angular system to angular modular system(detailed info in :johnpapa/angular-styleguide · GitHub).
I see no error on console or somewhere else but still ui-router doesn't to its job..

routes.js

```
 (function()    { 
    'use strict';
    angular
    .module('app')
    .config(routeConf);

    function routeConf($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
        $stateProvider
        .state('mainMenu', {
        //url: '/index',//causes navigation problems
        templateUrl: 'testing/pages/mainmenu.html',
    })
        .state('index', {
        //url: '/start',//causes navigation problems
        templateUrl: 'try.html',
    })
        .state('terminal', {
        //url: '/start',//causes navigation problems
        templateUrl: 'testing/pages/terminal.html',
    });
    }
})();
```

and script.js(app)

```
  (function() { 
  'use strict';
angular
  .module('app', [
    'ui.router'
  ]);
})();
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/VzAsH61OaZ97tyMhKkDJ?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialize angular.  You need to put something like:

```
<html ng-app="app">
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/NzqnTwkk1SqkTfwAWvQM?p=preview

Also, you actually have to put something at the default route - in this case '/'.
So I directed your 'try.html' page to that spot.

```
.state('index', {
    url: '/',
    templateUrl: 'try.html',
})
```